# JavaFX AnimationTimer seems out of sync, untill window is resized

Tags: javafx-8

A little introduction: I've created a simple (for now) application which uses an `AnimationTimer` to update animations and draw objects to the `Canvas`. Everything runs smoothly and the timer adjusts its fps to the refresh-rate of my laptop (50/60Hz).

When I start the program however, there seems to be something wrong which causes my animations to appear 'jurky' or dropping frames, but the framerate stays a solid 60/50fps. Then when I resize the window for the first time (no difference how many), suddenly all the animations are super-smooth. After that, everything stays 'synced' no matter the resizes done.

What is the reason that the `AnimationTimer`starts 'out-of-sync' until the window is resized and can it be prevented?

#### Update

Added a code example. The problem is mostly visible when on 50Hz, but also exist on 60Hz. Using Eclipse on Windows 10 (first code-share, may be to much/missing things).

```
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    try {
        pane = new Pane();
        drawables = new ArrayList<>();
        canvas = new Canvas(400,400);
        canvas.widthProperty().bind(pane.widthProperty());
        canvas.heightProperty().bind(pane.heightProperty());
        GraphicsContext g = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();

        SimpleAnimatedCircle circle = new SimpleAnimatedCircle(20);
        circle.setX(100);
        circle.setY(50);
        
        timer = new AnimationTimer() {

            @Override
            public void handle(long now) {
                frameCount++;
                if (System.currentTimeMillis() > frameStart + 500) {
                    System.out.println("FPS: " + frameCount*2);
                    frameStart = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    frameCount = 0;
                }
                for (Drawable drawable:drawables) {
                    drawable.update();
                }
                g.setFill(Color.DARKSLATEBLUE);
                g.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
                circle.draw(g);
            }
        };
        timer.start();
        
        canvas.setOnMouseClicked((e) -> {
            circle.start();
        });
        
        pane.getChildren().add(canvas);
        Scene scene = new Scene(pane,400,400);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static class SimpleAnimatedCircle {
    
    double diameter;
    double x;
    double y;
    long startTime;
    double diffY = 300; // Animated distance over y-axis.
    double duration = 2000; // 2 second duration.
    
    public SimpleAnimatedCircle(double diameter) {
        this.diameter = diameter;
    }
    
    public void setX(double value) {
        x = value;
    }
    
    public void setY(double value) {
        y = value;
    }
    
    public void start() {
        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }
    
    public void draw(GraphicsContext g) {
        double animatedY = y;
        // Update the animation.
        if (System.currentTimeMillis() < startTime + duration) {
            animatedY = y + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) /
                    duration * diffY;
        }
        g.setFill(Color.ORANGE);
        g.fillOval(x, animatedY, diameter, diameter);
    }
}
```

Comment: are you okay posting your simple demo?

Comment: The project already had become a bit complex, so I've tried to remove as many unrelated stuff. Is this enough to test (edited question)? First code share.